# Image not loading within <img> tag but loads fine on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, tags

```
<img
    className="playerImg"
    alt={fullName}
    src="http://nhl.bamcontent.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/8447400.png"
/>
```

The src URL works fine in my browser but not in my React application NOTE: "fullName" is a prop I passed and it loads the value fine

Comment: When you run your react app, do any specific errors show up regarding the image?

Comment: It looks like the image is on an insecure server so you're getting an HTML page instead asking whether you want to proceed. You would have seen this error in your dev tools.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew and Andy I ended up inspecting the official NHL page and found where they got their images, I used this as the src for example https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/headshots/current/60x60/8479414.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Found the actual src URL which the NHL uses by inspecting their website, use this as an example https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/headshots/current/60x60/8479414.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).